# I can't see the version of python in cmd

Tags: python, django

When i type 'python −−version' on CMD; it does not show me the version of python i am using instead it displays:python: can't open file 'ΓêÆΓêÆversion': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: That's really weird. Does the same thing happen in powershell?

Comment: is python on path?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to find the python version which you can try:

1. In the CMD: `python -V`
2. In a python document you can import `sys` and print out `sys.version`
3. In a python document you can import `platform` and print out `platform.python_version()`

Hope that helps. If you have an issue with your python installation, you could try reinstalling it from scratch as well. If there is no issue with your python installation then check if it is in your path and accessible from your command line, if not then either add it to your path or open your command line into the folder with the python.exe file and run your commands directly in there.

Answer (score 0):

Access to a command-line/terminal window: Windows:  Win+R > type powershell > Enter/OK

```
$ python ––version
```

it has to give this result :

```
Python 3.7 (32-bit)
```

or:

```
Python 2.7 (32-bit)
```